# animation glitch in sunburst

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I started with the default [Sunburst example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063423) and tried to add an animation on click - clicking on a wedge makes that wedge the center element. This works great except in a few cases - it looks like if the depth goes above 2 (0 based) then some wedges don't animate correctly; they seem to start the animation in the wrong place, but end up in the correct place.

Here is what I think is the relevant code, and I hope it's useful to someone else:

```
animate = function (d) {
            var oldDs = [], topD, includeds;

            if (animating)
                return;
            animating = true;

            topD = (d == selected && d.parent) ? d.parent : d;
            if (selected == topD) {
                animating = false;
                return;
            }
            selected = topD;

            svg.selectAll("path").filter(function (f) {
                return (!isDescendant(f, topD))
            }).transition().duration(1000).style("opacity", "0").attr("pointer-events","none");

            includeds = svg.datum(topD).selectAll("path").filter(function (f) {
                return isDescendant(f, topD);
            });

            // step 1 - save the current arc settings
            includeds.data().each(function (d) {
                oldDs[d.ac_id] = {x: d.x, dx: d.dx, y: d.y, dy: d.dy};
            });

            // step 2 - recalculate arc settings and animate
            includeds.data(partition.nodes) // recalculates
                .transition().duration(1000).attrTween("d", function (d) {
                    var oldD = oldDs[d.ac_id],
                        interpolator = d3.interpolateObject(oldD, d);
                    return function (t) {
                        return arc(interpolator(t));
                    }
                }).style("opacity", "1").attr("pointer-events","all");

            setTimeout(function(){ animating = false; }, 1000);
        };
```

Because my code doesn't have anything to do with the depth, I expect the issue is somewhere else, but I haven't been able to find it. The glitch seems to affect all browsers (at least Chrome, Firefox, and IE).

So, my question: what's the issue and how can I fix it?